# How to capitalize the last letter of each word in a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, letter, capitalize

I want to capitalize the last letter of each Word in a string given in parameter of a function.

Let's say that string is "yOu aRe KiNd". I want to transform it like so = "yoU arE kinD"

I tried to first put all the string into lower and then reverse it and then put first letter of the reverse string to Caps and then reverse it again but it doesn't work. It displays the full string into Lower letters.

[image]

Comment: Don't post images of code. Copy/paste the code into the question itself.

Comment: Title asks different thing as your text.

Comment: I have rolled this back to the last good version. Please do not substantially change the topic of a question once it has acquired answers.

Answer (score 1):

You have almost the answer, you just need to place your `strtolower()` call first.

```
function phrase(string $str = null){
    return strrev(ucwords(strrev(strtolower($str))));
}

echo phrase("yOu aRe KiNd");  // yoU arE kinD
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the string to lowercase *first*, and then reverse, capitalise and reverse it again:

```
$str =  "yOu aRe KiNd";
echo strrev(ucwords(strrev(strtolower($str)))) . "\n";
```

Output

```
yoU arE kinD
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/gWa6C)

An alternative way to do it is by using `preg_replace_callback`, matching the character at the end of a word and then converting that to uppercase in the callback:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/[a-z](?![a-z])/', function ($m) { return strtoupper($m[0]); }, strtolower($str));
```

Output:

```
yoU arE kinD
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/jEldo)